# i want to stop the creation of object id field in mongo db so that when i will insert the data into the collection

Tags: mongodb

I want to prevent the creation of object id field in mongodb database so that the object id should not get created at the time of inserting the document into the collection

Answer (score 1):

The `_id` field is [required](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) in every document:

> In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique _id
>   field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the
>   _id field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an ObjectId for the _id field.

You can specify the `_id` value at the time of insertion to prevent the value from being auto-generated.